# dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval() has been deprecated Fitness History API

Tags: android, google-fit

I am writing a code to allow a user to add steps count to the Fitness History API within a defined period of time. I am using Fitness History API for Android referring to their documentation. I couldn't find the new method for `setTimeInterval()` is there any new method or workaround for this?

```
int stepCountDelta = 950;
        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
        DataPoint dataPoint =
                dataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Even `getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);` setInt() has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataPoint#setTimestamp(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> ```
> public DataPoint setTimestamp (long timestamp, TimeUnit timeUnit)
> ```
>
> **This method is deprecated.**
> use `DataPoint.Builder` to create `DataPoint` instances.

So, do something like:

```
DataPoint dataPoint =
    DataPoint.builder(dataSource)
        .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();

DataSet.Builder dataSet = DataSet.builder(dataSource);    
dataSet.addDataPoint(dataPoint);
```